# Performance of Cypher executed from Java

Tags: java, neo4j

I have this Cypher query:

```
match (n:USERNODE)-[:TRAVELING]->(t) 
where ID(n) = 3066 and ID(t) = 3072
with n,t
match (n)-[:INTERESTED_IN*..2]->(i)
with n,t,i
match (t)-[:TRAVELING_TO]->(c)
with n,t,i,c
match (c)<-[:TRAVELING_TO]-(t1)<-[:TRAVELING]-(u)
where t1.openToMeetTravelers = true
and NOT (u)-[:NOT_INTERESTED|MATCH|BLOCKED]-(n)
and NOT (u)<-[:INTERESTED]-(n)
and ANY (x IN u.languages WHERE x IN n.languages)
and ((t1.startDate > (t.startDate + 6400000) and t1.startDate < (t.endDate - 86400000))
   or (t1.endDate > (t.startDate + 6400000) and t1.endDate < (t.endDate - 86400000)))
and (1480550400000 - u.birthdate) >= 31556952000 * t.ageMin
and (1480550400000 - u.birthdate) <= 31556952000 * t.ageMax
and (1480550400000 - n.birthdate) >= 31556952000 * t1.ageMin
and (1480550400000 - n.birthdate) <= 31556952000 * t1.ageMax
with n,u,i,t1,t,c
match (u)-[:INTERESTED_IN*..2]->(i)
return u
limit 10
```

It works perfectly good.

When I execute it from the web client, It's executed within **~100ms**.

When I execute the same query from my Java app, it takes **forever** to execute and also for each iteration (called using it.next()).

Java Code below :

NB: I'm using Neo4j 3.0 community.

```
try ( Transaction tx = dbService.beginTx() ){
    Node fu = dbService.findNode(NodeLabels.USERNODE, "id", userId);
    Node tu = dbService.findNode(NodeLabels.TRAVEL, "id", travelId);
        StringBuilder q = new StringBuilder();
        q.append("MATCH (n:USERNODE)-[:TRAVELING]->(t) ");
        q.append("WHERE ID(n) = ");
        q.append(fu.getId());
        q.append(" AND ID(t) = ");
        q.append(tu.getId());
        q.append(" WITH n,t ");
        q.append("match (n)-[:INTERESTED_IN*..2]->(i) ");
        q.append("with n,t,i ");
        q.append("match (t)-[:TRAVELING_TO]->(c) ");
        q.append("with n,t,i,c ");
        q.append("match (c)<-[:TRAVELING_TO]-(t1)<-[:TRAVELING]-(u) ");
        q.append("where t1.openToMeetTravelers = true ");
        q.append("and NOT (u)-[:NOT_INTERESTED|MATCH|BLOCKED]-(n) ");
        q.append("and NOT (u)<-[:INTERESTED]-(n) ");
        q.append("and ANY (x IN u.languages WHERE x IN n.languages) ");
        q.append("and ((t1.startDate > (t.startDate + 6400000) and t1.startDate < (t.endDate - 86400000)) ");
        q.append("or (t1.endDate > (t.startDate + 6400000) and t1.endDate < (t.endDate - 86400000))) ");
        q.append("and ({NOW_IN_MILLIS} - u.birthdate) >= 31556952000 * t.ageMin ");
        q.append("and ({NOW_IN_MILLIS} - u.birthdate) <= 31556952000 * t.ageMax ");
        q.append("and ({NOW_IN_MILLIS} - n.birthdate) >= 31556952000 * t1.ageMin ");
        q.append("and ({NOW_IN_MILLIS} - n.birthdate) <= 31556952000 * t1.ageMax ");
        q.append("with n,u,i,t1,t,c ");
        q.append("match (u)-[:INTERESTED_IN*..2]->(i) ");
        q.append("return u ");
        q.append("limit ").append(page.getPageSize());

        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        params.put("NOW_IN_MILLIS", System.currentTimeMillis());

        ResourceIterator<Node> resultIterator = dbService.execute(q.toString(), params).columnAs("u");
        try {
            while ( resultIterator.hasNext() )
            {
                Node n = resultIterator.next();
                System.out.println(n.getId());
            }
            tx.success();
            return r;
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Not an answer but a few observations: 1) you should do is parameterize your query so it does not have to be recompiled every request; 2) don't use the `id` of the node as an identifier; it is reusable.

Comment: 1- First it was parametrized but I changed it trying to figure out if that could be the issue. 2- I omitted the first part of the Java code where I find the nodes using their (logical) ids (I do that for some tests before executing the main query showed in the question). Thanks!

Comment: To clarify @DaveBennett's comment #2: a native neo4j ID can be reassigned to a different node after the original node is deleted.  Also, once you parameterize everything that should be parameterized (this includes the `LIMIT` count), there is no need to re-generate the query string every time. It can just be a constant.

Comment: Thanks. fu and tu in my java code are Node objects that I fetch 2 lines before the lines I pasted. I'm going to edit my answer to be clearer

Comment: Where is the transaction `tx` started? Are you doing too much within one transaction? Also, if other transactions can be deleting nodes at the same time, your use of native IDs is risky.

Comment: You can just pass `userId` and `travelId` as parameters and replace your 1st 5 `append` calls with something like this: `q.append("MATCH (n:USERNODE {id: {userId}})-[:TRAVELING]->(t {id: {travelId}})");` You can then remove the 2 lines of code to get those nodes (just so you can get their native IDs) -- those are extra hits to the DB.

Comment: I posted the full code there. I've missed copying the Transaction line.

Comment: Concerning the native ID. First I did it using the logical ID, after that I changed it to native ID to see if it's faster (I suppose it is even if not too much)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is running in a transaction, and the transaction will only finish (either because of `tx.success()` or because the outer `try` block implicitly closes `tx`) *after* your `while` loop is done processing the results. If there are a lot of results, this can take a long time.

IMPORTANT ASIDE: You have a [subtle bug](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/javadocs/index.html?org/neo4j/graphdb/GraphDatabaseService.html) in your code as well. `tx.success()` may not be called if the inner `try` block throws an exception. In that situation, the outer `try` block will automatically close (and essentially roll back the transaction, which may be more expensive than `success()`, even though your current code does no writes). The main problem comes if this method is ever called by another method that already has an open transaction. In that case, if this method's *nested transaction* is rolled back, then if that other transaction tries to call `success()` neo4j will throw an exception (which is probably not what you want). Therefore, you should move the `tx.success()` call *after* your inner `try` block.

Comment: I got the subtle bug thanks. But your explanation about the execution time doesn't explain the big execution time difference between the API call (using the web interface) and the Cypher call from the Java code. The cypher query is exactly the same and the number of results is limited to 10 or am I missing something? I added traces within the loop on the results and it shows 180s to iterate on the first row, 200s for the 2nd row then it hangs in the 3rd iteration forever.